# How to check the domain name availability on AWS using API in Laravel?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api

Basically, I wanna check the domain name availability on AWS from Laravel. so I have to call AWS API to see the response, if it is available. how to do that? any guideline please?

Comment: Your question title and body contents don't seem to match. Can you confirm what you're asking? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by using the AWS SDK. Once you have pulled in the SDK (recommended via composer) then you can use the `Route53Domains` client to interact with these APIs.

The specific function you want to call is the [checkDomainAvailability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-route53domains-2014-05-15.html#checkdomainavailability). This will allow you to see the availability status of the domain name you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Chris Williams instruction and it helped me to solve the issue. here is my code, maybe it helps someone else.

```
use Aws\Route53Domains\Route53DomainsClient;

class testController extends Controller
{

   public function index (){

    $client = Route53DomainsClient::factory(array(
        'region'      => 'us-east-1',
        'version'     => 'latest',
       ));
    // dd($client);

    $result = $client->checkDomainAvailability([
    'DomainName' => 'zahirblog.com', // REQUIRED
    // 'IdnLangCode' => '',
       ]);

    dd($result);

    return view('welcome');

    }
}
```